# Getting Error when try to get the ZoneName from DNS

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, windows-server-2008-r2

Getting Error when try to get the ZoneName from DNS.

```
$zoneNames = (Get-DnsServerZone | Where-Object {
    $_.IsReverseLookupZone -eq $true
}).ZoneName
```

Error Message:

> The term 'Get-DnsServerZone' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Comment: `Add-WindowsFeature RSAT-DNS-Server`. This will only work on server installations of Windows.

Comment: @JeroenMostert

Executed the mentioned command but still getting the same error.

Comment: The cmdlet is part of the `DnsServer` module, which should have been auto-loaded when you invoked the cmdlet. What does `Import-Module DnsServer` say? (And what version and edition of Windows are you on?)

Comment: Error out - `Import-Module : The specified module 'DnsServer' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module di
rectory.`

I am working in Windows Server 2008R2

Comment: Ah, should have asked that first. :-P You're out of luck, `DnsServer` requires Server 2012 at minimum. If you're stuck with Windows 2008 R2, you can't use these cmdlets and are restricted to WMI, which is [far more cumbersome](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/09/13/manage-dns-in-a-windows-environment-by-using-powershell/).

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert.. But is there any way to get out from that error and get the required details.

Comment: Use [`dnscmd`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772069.aspx) and parse the output.

Comment: WMI, or what @AnsgarWiechers said, though the output of `dnscmd` can be a little fiddly because it's geared towards humans, not parsers. `(dnscmd /enumzones /reverse | select-string "[0-9.]+\.in-addr\.arpa").Matches.Value` should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the `DnsServer` module that contains the `Get-DnsServerZone` cmdlet ships with Windows Server 2012 and newer.

On 2008 R2, you'll have to use either [`dnscmd`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772069.aspx) or query the `MicrosoftDNS` WMI namespace on the target DNS server:

```
$ZoneNames = (Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\MicrosoftDNS -Class MicrosoftDNS_Zone -Filter 'Reverse = true' -ComputerName targetdnsserver.domain.tld).Name
```